# Awt Components are not shown

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

I'm developping Library System with Java in awt framework.
 If user click add book interface open in same window with different components.For example after clicking,add book menu components removing and add books components added to same window. My problems is after user in section add book if user click menu section,menu component is not shown although components added.Main activity:
      public class LibrarySystemInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame implements

```
PanelWorker {

         private FileReaderWriter writer;
        private LibraryIterator forCode ;
        private Library kutuphane;
        private Collection collection;
        private int count=1;
        private PanelWorker getToWork;
        private Library library = null;
       private static  LibrarySystemInterface instance;

       public LibrarySystemInterface() {
            initComponents();
            writer=new FileReaderWriter("prevent");

            kutuphane=Library.getInstance();

        }                        
        private void initComponents() {
            panel1 = new java.awt.Panel();
            label1 = new java.awt.Label();
            list1 = new java.awt.List();
            label2 = new java.awt.Label();
            list2 = new java.awt.List();
            ekle = new java.awt.Button();
            sil = new java.awt.Button();
            ara = new java.awt.Button();
            iade = new java.awt.Button();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            label1.setText("Butun Kitaplarin Listesi");

            list1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    list1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            label2.setText("Odunc Verilcek Kitaplarin Listesi");

            ekle.setLabel("Kitap Ekle");
            ekle.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    ekleActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            sil.setLabel("Kitap Sil");
            sil.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    silActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            ara.setActionCommand("Kitap Ara");
            ara.setLabel("Kitap Ara");
            ara.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    araActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            iade.setLabel("Kitap Iade");
            iade.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    iadeActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            javax.swing.GroupLayout panel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel1);
            panel1.setLayout(panel1Layout);
            panel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(ara, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(sil, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(ekle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 171, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(iade, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(list1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                            .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addComponent(list2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(0, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            panel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(ekle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(sil, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED))
                        .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(list1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(2, 2, 2)))
                    .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(ara, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(iade, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(list2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            );

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }                     

        private void ekleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
                                   panel1.removeAll();


                    getToWork=PanelFactory.getWork("add");
                    this.add(getToWork.builder());
                    this.repaint();
                    this.validate();      
        }                                    


        public static void main(String args[]) {
          instance=LibrarySystemInterface.getInstance();
        }
        public static LibrarySystemInterface getInstance() {
            if (instance==null)
                return instance=new LibrarySystemInterface();
            else    return instance;
        }


        private java.awt.Button ara;
        private java.awt.Button ekle;
        private java.awt.Button iade;
        private java.awt.Label label1;
        private java.awt.Label label2;
        private java.awt.List list1;
        private java.awt.List list2;
        private java.awt.Panel panel1;
        private java.awt.Button sil;
        // End of variables declaration                   

        @Override
        public Panel builder() {
             this.initComponents();
            updateNList();
           return panel1;
        }
        public void updateNList(){
            list1.removeAll();
            ArrayList<Collection> item=new ArrayList<Collection>();
            kutuphane=library.getInstance();
            forCode= kutuphane.iterator();  
            while(!forCode.hasNext()){
                collection=(Collection) forCode.next();
                String itemStr=collection.type + ", " + collection.name + ", " + collection.auther + ", " + collection.date
                        + ", " + collection.code;
                list2.add(itemStr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Add book section

```
 public class EkleInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame implements PanelWorker{


        private FileReaderWriter writer;
        private LibraryIterator forCode ;
        private Library kutuphane;
        private Collection collection;
        private int count=1;
        private PanelWorker getToWork;
        private Library library = null;

        public EkleInterface() {
            initComponents();
            writer=new FileReaderWriter("prevent");

            kutuphane=Library.getInstance();


        private void initComponents() {

            panel2 = new java.awt.Panel();
            label1 = new java.awt.Label();
            textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
            label2 = new java.awt.Label();
            textField2 = new java.awt.TextField();
            label3 = new java.awt.Label();
            textField3 = new java.awt.TextField();
            label4 = new java.awt.Label();
            textField4 = new java.awt.TextField();
            ekle = new java.awt.Button();
            Menu = new java.awt.Button();
            label5 = new java.awt.Label();
            list2 = new java.awt.List();
            label6 = new java.awt.Label();
            list1 = new java.awt.List();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            panel2.setName("");

            label1.setText("Tur:");

            textField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    textField1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            label2.setText("Ismi");

            textField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    textField2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            label3.setText("Yazari");

            textField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    textField3ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            label4.setText("Yayınlanma Tarihi");

            textField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    textField4ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            ekle.setLabel("Ekle");
            ekle.setName(""); // NOI18N
            ekle.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    ekleActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });   
            Menu.setLabel("Menu");
            Menu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    MenuActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });    
            label5.setText("Butun Kitaplarin Listesi");   
            label6.setText("Odunc Verilcek Kitaplarin Listesi");
            list1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    list1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
            javax.swing.GroupLayout panel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel2);
            panel2.setLayout(panel2Layout);
            panel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                            .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(label5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addComponent(list2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(ekle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                            .addComponent(Menu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(label4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                    .addComponent(textField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(label6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap())
                        .addComponent(list1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            );
            panel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(label5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(textField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(list2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 88, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(10, 10, 10)))
                    .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(label4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(textField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(panel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(ekle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(Menu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addContainerGap(47, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(panel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(label6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(list1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            );

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }                       

        private void ekleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            String type=textField1.getText();
            String name=textField2.getText();
            String date=textField4.getText();
            String auther=textField3.getText();
            forCode= kutuphane.iterator();
            while(!forCode.hasNext()){
                collection=(Collection) forCode.next();
                count=collection.code+1;

            }
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/";
            String dbName = "kutuphane";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "123456";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                String query = " insert into kitaplar (tur,yazar,tarih, ismi)"
                + " values ( ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStmt.setString (1, type);
                preparedStmt.setString (2, auther);
                preparedStmt.setString   (3, date);
                preparedStmt.setString(4, name);

                preparedStmt.execute();

                conn.close();
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException k) {
            } catch (InstantiationException k) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException k) {
            } catch (SQLException k) {
            }
            kutuphane.addAggregate(collection=new Collection(type,name,auther,
                date,count));
            updateNList();
        }                                    
        private void MenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
             panel2.removeAll();


                    getToWork=PanelFactory.getWork("menu");
                    this.add(getToWork.builder());
                    this.repaint();
                    this.validate();      
        }                                    

        private java.awt.Button Menu;
        private java.awt.Button ekle;
        private java.awt.Label label1;
        private java.awt.Label label2;
        private java.awt.Label label3;
        private java.awt.Label label4;
        private java.awt.Label label5;
        private java.awt.Label label6;
        private java.awt.List list1;
        private java.awt.List list2;
        private java.awt.Panel panel2;
        private java.awt.TextField textField1;
        private java.awt.TextField textField2;
        private java.awt.TextField textField3;
        private java.awt.TextField textField4;

        public Panel builder() {
            initComponents();
            updateNList();
           return panel2;
        }

       public void updateNList(){
            list1.removeAll();

            ArrayList<Collection> item=new ArrayList<Collection>();




            kutuphane=library.getInstance();
            forCode= kutuphane.iterator();

            while(!forCode.hasNext()){
                collection=(Collection) forCode.next();
                String itemStr=collection.type + ", " + collection.name + ", " + collection.auther + ", " + collection.date
                        + ", " + collection.code;
                list2.add(itemStr);
            }
        }

    }
```

Interface:

```
 public interface PanelWorker {
        public Panel builder();

    }
public class PanelFactory {
                    public static PanelWorker getWork(String whereTo){
                        if(whereTo.equals("add")){
                            return new EkleInterface();
                    }
                    else if (whereTo.equals("delete")){
                        return new SilInterci();
                    }

                else if (whereTo.equals("menu"))
                    return new LibrarySystemInterface();
                else if(whereTo.equals("search"))
                    return new AraInterface();
                else if(whereTo.equals("rentFinish"))
                    return new IadeInterface();
                return null;

            }
         }
```

Comment: Don't mix Swing components (like `JFrame`) with AWT components (like `Panel`, `Label`,  `List` or `Button`).  Use all Swing (`JPanel`, `JLabel`,  `JList` & `JButton`).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).